# Optimizing a render-to-texture process

Tags: c++, 3d, glsl

I'm developing a render-to-texture process that involves using several cameras which render an entire scene of geometry.  The output of these cameras is then combined and mapped directly to the screen by converting each geometry's vertex coordinates to screen coordinates in a vertex shader (I'm using GLSL, here).

The process works fine, but I've realized a small problem:  every RTT camera I create will create a texture the same dimensions as the screen output.  That is, if my viewport is sized to 1024x1024, even if the geometry occupies a 256x256 section of the screen, each RTT camera will render the 256x256 geometry in a 1024x1024 texture.

The solution seems reasonably simple - adjust the RTT camera texture sizes to match the actual screen area the geometry occupies, but I'm not sure how to do that.  That is, how can I (for example) determine that a geometry occupies a 256x256 area of a screen so that I can correspondingly set the RTT camera's output texture to 256x256 pixels?

The API I use (OpenSceneGraph) uses axis-aligned bounding boxes, so I'm out of luck there..

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

why out of luck? can't you use the axis-aligned bounding box to compute the area?

My idea:

- take the 8 corner points of the bounding box and project them onto the image plane of the camera.
- for the resulting 2d points on the image plane you can determine an axis-aligned 2d bounding box again

This should be a correct upper bound for the space the geometry can occupy.